# How do I find my memory leaky lists in flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, performance, memory-leaks, flutter-devtools

I used the Flutter Dev Tool Memory view to look for some issues in my performance.
To me it looks like I am having some issues with my lists.

[image]

The total size and the instances keep rising when doing some actions in my app. Is there any way to get more details e.g. the name of the lists/class/files where these badly managed lists are located?

I tried to use the Trace function but it seemed really laggy for some reason.

Any ideas on how to approach this or do I have to go through all the code manually and just test things out?